# Should you use an equivalence or an implication in a definition?

Tags: soft-question, first-order-logic

In a definition like the following:

> An object $x$ is called $P$ if [and only if] it has properties $p$ and $q.$

should one use an implication (if) or an equivalence (if and only if)?

It makes sense to use an equivalence seen as this is a definition and not a set of necessary conditions. However, in many texts I see the use of just an implication. Which is correct in the formal or stylistic sense?

Comment: I do agree with you! One must use equivalence! :)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566565/are-if-and-iff-interchangeable-in-definitions

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common to use *if* instead of *iff* in definitions because it reads better.

An alternative is to use *when* instead of *if*.

A definition like “$x$ is called a *blip* when $x$ satisfies $p$ and $q$” is metalanguage.

The mathematical statement “$x$ is a *blip* iff $x$ satisfies $p$ and $q$” is true, as consequence of the definition, but is not quite the same thing.