# Definition of Equivalence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, definition, relations

I was going through the text "Discrete Mathematics and its Application" by Kenneth Rosen (5th Edition) where I am across the definition of equivalence relation and felt that it is one sided.

> Definition: **A relation on a set A is called an equivalence relation if it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.**

Now let us analyze the situation of what equivalence is meant to us intuitively.

Let there be a binary relation $R$ defined on a set $A$. Now we suppose that $R$ be reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

So we have for $a,b,c \in A$

1. $a R a$ (by the reflexive property of R)
2. if $a R b$ then $b R a$  (by the symmetric property of R)
3. if $a R b$ and $b R c$ then $aRc$ (by the transitive property of R)

Intuitively we can satisfy ourselves with the fact that the above are the necessary conditions for $R$ to be equivalent. So "if $R$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, then $R$ is an equivalence relation"

Now working our intuition for equivalence relation $\sim$ we note the following.

Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on a set A, then for $a,b,c \in A$ we have,

1. $a \sim a$ (by the intuitive knowledge of what $\sim$ means)
2. if $a\sim b$ then $b \sim a$ (by the intuitive knowledge of what $\sim$ means)
3. if $a\sim b$ and $b \sim c$ then $a\sim c$ (by the intuitive knowledge of what $\sim$ means)

Now we see that (1) implies $\sim$ is reflexive, (2) implies that $\sim$ is symmetric and (3) implies that $\sim$ is transitive.

So we have "if $\sim$ is an equivalent relation then $\sim$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive"

From the two intuitive implications we can conclude that **A relation on a set A is called an equivalence relation if and only if it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.** and not what the book says. This definition makes quite sense unlike the book definition which says that if $R$ fails to be either reflexive or symmetric or transitive then $R$ may or may not be an equivalence relation, which after all gives a weird feeling.

Correct me if my logic is wrong.

Comment: ??? What the book phrasing implies is that if one of  the three properties fails to be satisfied in a single case, it is *not* an equivalence relation.

Comment: Then what the book meant is *iff* and not simply *if* @Bernard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word “if” in a definition should be understood to mean “if and only if”.

See [Are "if" and "iff" interchangeable in definitions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566565/are-if-and-iff-interchangeable-in-definitions) for a longer discussion.

Comment: at times implicit assumptions like this leads to ambiguity.

Comment: This isn't an implicit assumption and it's not ambiguous.  You simply misunderstood.