# Does a root of a polynomial occur iff $p(x) = 0$?

Tags: logic, polynomials

Is it appropriate to use **iff** in this case? I don't know if there is another case which is sufficient to show that $x$ is a root of a polynomial which would mean it is NOT **iff**.

Comment: "*I don't know if there is another case*" $\;-\;$ What is the definition for the "root of a polynomial" you are using?

Comment: Maybe you mean [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566565/are-if-and-iff-interchangeable-in-definitions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by a root of a polynomial $p$ you mean a number $a$ such that $p(x)= q(x)(x-a)$ for some polynomial $q$. By polynomial division, you can always write $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)+b$, where $b$ is a scalar. Then $p(a)=b$, so desired factorization exists if and only if $p(a)=0$.

Comment: yes this is what I meant. Sorry if i was unclear

Comment: **Does this also hold true if it is a polynomial with complex coefficients?**

Comment: Yes, you can perform polynomial division also for complex polynomials (try proving this!), so the same argument will work.