# 'if' and 'if and only if' equivalence in mathematical definition

Tags: definition, article-writing

I am always puzzled by the difference between 'if' and 'if and only if'. I know that an 'if' statement is one-way while an 'if and only if' is two-way. However, I also know that it is a convention to use 'if' statement in a mathematical definition. For example, 'a rectangle is a square if its two adjacent sides are equal in length'. It is puzzling to me why use this convention in the first place when this is clearly an if and only if statement. This convention feels logically inconsistent to me because it uses a one-way statement to describe something that is inherently two-way. To see the issue, imagine you are not told this example is in fact a definition. How are you going to judge if it is just an 'if' statement or an 'if and only if' statement in disguise?

EDIT: since there are many answers to this question, let me zoom the question into a more specific one: Given an if statement without being told whether the statement is a definition or not, how to judge if it is just an 'if' statement or an 'if and only if' statement in disguise?

EDIT2: as someone has pointed out, the example I gave on the square is actually a theorem, not a definition. So consider the following definition instead: a square is a regular quadrilateral. (an equivalent statement is (an object is a square if it is regular quadrilateral). I guess my confusion can be rephrased as how to tell apart a definition and a theorem, because if I know this example is a theorem, then the 'if' statement cannot mean 'if and only if'. In example it might be trivial to tell it is in fact a definition, but I suspect in general without being explicitly told, it can be difficult to tell them apart.

Comment: This has been discussed before, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566565/42969 and the (more thatn 40) Q&As linked to it.

Comment: Can you give an example of a *“if statement without being told whether the statement is a definition or not”*? Usually that is clear from the context.

Comment: Your question shows that you recognise the significance of whether or not the word "if" is occurring in a definition. However, the example you give is not the definition of a square. It is a result about two previously defined objects, rectangles and squares, and its converse may be obvious to you but it does require (an admittedly simple) proof. Therefore the "if" should not be automatically interpreted as an "iff".

Comment: I think that this is usually done when the “only if” portion is either assumed, known, or irrelevant.

Comment: @MartinR yeah so I guess what I really want to understand is how we can tell apart a definition from other statements (theorem, lemma, proposition, etc.) without being explicitly told. Are there any subtle differences in the structure of those statements?

Answer (score 1):

> I am always puzzled by the difference between 'if' and 'if and only if'. I know that an 'if' statement is one-way while an 'if and only if' is two-way. However, I also know that it is a convention to use 'if' statement in a mathematical definition.

So, you are not puzzled, but in fact do fully understand the logic of, as well as the culture surrounding, 'if' versus 'iff'.

> How are you going to judge if it is just an 'if' statement or an 'if and only if' statement in disguise?

Outside of definitions, ‘if’, ‘only if’ and ‘iff’ convey distinct ideas; none precludes any of the others. Your **actual** question is rather this: how to judge whether an 'if' statement is a definition or not a definition?

Definitions in mathematical texts are usually well-signposted. It also helps to pay attention to the statement's context and purpose (by carefully reading its surrounding text, including noticing whether the statement is introducing some object or phrase).

> For example, 'a rectangle is a square if its two adjacent sides are equal in length'.  To see the issue, imagine you are not told this example is in fact a definition.

No, this example is a theorem, not a definition.

> It is puzzling to me why use this convention in the first place when this is clearly an if and only if statement. This convention feels logically inconsistent to me because it uses a one-way statement to describe something that is inherently two-way.

Omitting the converse direction of a bidirectional statement is neither illogical nor inconsistent.

You say that a definition is "clearly" an iff statement, and is "inherently" bidirectional. This sounds to me like supporting reasons for the convention—i.e., agreement— that a definition's converse direction is tacit.

Moreover, observe that unlike a standard-issue proposition, [a definition is not a usual equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/568119/21813). Because its left side has no initial truth value, a definition is not falsifiable, and the ‘if’ or ‘iff’ or $\text‘{\overset{\text{def}}\iff}\text’$ within it isn't your run-of-the-mill inferential implication. As a metalogical biconditional, a definition is regarded differently from a regular statement.

Comment: I love that your answer is, basically, no, you are not confused ;-)

Comment: So you are saying without the context, is it impossible to know whether an 'if' statement is truly an 'if' statement is that correct?

Comment: @ryang am I correct to interpret your latest comment as: if no context on whether a statement is a definition is given explicitly, we cannot tell whether an 'if' statement actually means 'if and only if' or not?

Comment: @ryang My two comments essentially ask the same thing, which I don't think your first comment under your proposed answer actually addressed. I asked this question precisely because of the last paragraph in your proposed answer. I wanted to know without the context is it possible to discern with 100% certainty whether a given statement is a definition. I am not interpreting your answer in a way you did not intend, I am just asking a different question (maybe I shound't have written 'so you are saying' and directly ask it instead).

Comment: @ryang Regarding your EDIT: I am not sure why the statement in my EDIT2 must be a definition even without being explicitly stated. It could be that there is another different statement which is the definition of a square, so the one I stated could be a theorem.

Comment: @ryang 1.i would have taken down 'So you are saying' part if I can do so in the comment section but sadly I can't. 2. here I did not say you suggested that, but that is what I care about. In other words, if the statement in my EDIT2 doesn't have to be a definition, then context is necessary to determine the nature of the statement. 3. I take it you agreed with my last sentence. So if without context, it is indeed hard to say for sure whether a statement is a definition, then it is also safe to say without context, it is hard to determine whether an 'if' statement means 'if' or 'iff'.

Comment: @ryang 'A definition is a special type of biconditional, and is accorded a different status from a regular statement'. So the 'if' in a definition is different from 'iff' in a non-definition statement,  in that 'its left side has no initial truth value'. So without context, can you tell with certainty the 'if' in some statement denotes this special biconditionality or just a regular 'if'