# Confused about delta-epsilon definition of limits / definitions of things in general

Tags: calculus

Paraphrasing [the delta-epsilon definition of limits on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit),

"Given function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and reals $a,L\in\mathbb{R}$. We say $\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}} f(x)=L$ if $P(L)$ holds"

Where

$P(L):=\left[\forall \varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}:\exists \delta\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}:\forall x\in \mathbb{R}: (0<|x-a|<\delta)\implies \left(\left|f(x)-L\right|<\varepsilon\right)\right]$

In short, it says: $P(L)\implies \stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}} f(x)=L\hspace{2em}$ (1)

It doesn't say: $P(L)\iff \stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}} f(x)=L\hspace{2.6em}$ (2)

It seems that (1) is weaker than (2). Statement (1) suffices when we wish to prove $\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to 3}}2x=6$ (simply show that $P(6)$ holds with $f(x)=2x, a=3$), but what if we want to prove the following?

"Assume $\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}f(x)$ and $\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}g(x)$ exist. It follows that
$\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}\left(
f(x)\cdot g(x)
\right)=\left(
    \stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}f(x)
\right)\cdot 
\left(
    \stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}g(x)
\right)$"

Although I think the above statement is true, I don't think you can prove it given the delta-epsilon definition of limits described in (1). One *can* show that if
$[\forall \varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}:\exists \delta_1\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: (0<|x-a|<\delta_1)\implies (|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)]$ holds and
$[\forall \varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}:\exists \delta_2\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: (0<|x-a|<\delta_2)\implies (|g(x)-M|<\varepsilon)]$ holds for some $L,M\in \mathbb{R}$, then it follows that $\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}\left(
f(x)\cdot g(x)
\right)=\left(
    \stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}f(x)
\right)\cdot 
\left(
    \stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}}g(x)
\right)=L\cdot M$

The issue is that given $\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}} f(x)$ exists, (let's call it $L$) it doesn't follow that $[\forall \varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}:\exists \delta_1\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: (0<|x-a|<\delta_1)\implies (|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)]$

Likewise, given $\stackrel{\lim}{_{x\to a}} g(x)$ exists, (let's call it $M$) it doesn't follow that $[\forall \varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}:\exists \delta_2\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}: \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: (0<|x-a|<\delta_2)\implies (|g(x)-M|<\varepsilon)]$

I suppose a more general question is, whenever a math text says something like "We say $x$ is [terminology] if $x$ has [property]" e.g. "We say a natural $x$ is happy if $x$ is divisible by 7", am I supposed to interpret this text as meaning "We say a natural $x$ is happy if **and only if** $x$ is divisible by 7"? The first statement says that 0, 7, 14 etc are happy numbers, but says nothing about whether or not 3 is happy, while the second says 3 is definitively not a happy number.

Comment: The definition of a limit is given by property (2). So the epsilon-delta stuff is precisely the definition of a limit. It's common when defining something to use such phrasing.

Comment: [Lots of good discussion on your general question here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566565/are-if-and-iff-interchangeable-in-definitions)

Comment: You are overthinking it. $P(L)$ is the *definition* of what a limit is. And a definition can only be an *if and only if* condition...

Comment: Understood. This is what I suspected but I wasn't sure. Thank you all for your help! (: