# Why it's important to state the trichotomy property in the definition of order of set?

Tags: real-analysis

First, it's my first try in real analysis. I study "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin.

In the definition 1.5 of order of a set, I quote:

> Let $S$ be a set. An order on $S$ is a relation, denoted by $<$, with the following two
> properties:
>
> (i) If $x \in S$ and $y \in S$ then one and only one of
> the statements $x<y, x=y, x>y$ is true.
>
> (ii) If $x,y,z\in S$, if $x<y$ and $y<z$, then $x<z$.

My question is, isn't that property is so obvious with no counter example - as I think - ? why it's so important to state this particular property? why doesn't the second propery being enough for defining order?

Comment: (ii) doesn't imply (i) in general... what exactly confuses you?

Comment: There are plenty of relations that fail to satisfy either one of these axioms.  There are relations on sets with--for certain points--none of $x<y$, $x=y$, or $x>y$ being true as $x$ and $y$ aren't comparable under the relation

Comment: @Randall So the confusion comes because I restrict my thinking in numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Look at some of the examples here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

Comment: See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367583/ .

Comment: @Randall So I can replace the first property with less rigorous terms to be "$x$ and $y$ are comparable". Thanks a lot for clarifying :)

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  If they are comparable they are either equal or one must be greater than the other.  The second property says that you cannot have both $x < y$ and $y<x$, for then $x < x$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the order $\subsetneq$ on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. It is clearly the case that if $A\subsetneq B$ and $B\subsetneq C$, then $A\subsetneq C$, however, as as example, none of $[0,2]\subsetneq[1,3]$, $[0,2]\supsetneq[1,3]$, $[0,2]=[1,3]$ is true.